# Starting Apache through control panel returns not reponding

Tags: xampp

I was using xampp 3.1.0 previously . It was working fine until one day it started behaving like this . On startup apache is not on , and when I try to start through the control panel ,it crashes and then I want to restart it . Could nt find any error's in any logs . Please Help ...

Comment: Sorry, without your configs I doubt we can really help you...

Comment: Thankss.. it was a typo . Solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by reinstalling the xampp, in each case chek port 80

Comment: I think it would be better to post this as a comment as it does not provide a detailed and/or general way of resolving that.